# How to get attribute of a directory like last access and last modify

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I wanted to get timestamps of a directory and then show it to the user. I have written the following function, but it doesn't work when I give a full path of a directory to present its timestamp like access time. What should I do to fix this issue? I didn't know how should I open a directory and get information about its timestamps correctly for regular files my code works fine but when I wanted to extract information about directory it doesn't work.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

BOOL GetLastWriteTimeDirectory(HANDLE arg_h_file, LPSTR arg_lpsz_string, DWORD arg_dw_size)
{
    FILETIME ft_CreateTime, ft_AccessTime, ft_WriteTime;
    SYSTEMTIME st_UTC, st_Local;
    DWORD dw_Return;

    // Retrieve the file times for the file.
    if (!GetFileTime(arg_h_file, &ft_CreateTime, &ft_AccessTime, &ft_WriteTime))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Convert the last-write time to local time.
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft_WriteTime, &st_UTC);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &st_UTC, &st_Local);

    // Build a string showing the date and time.
    dw_Return = StringCchPrintfA(arg_lpsz_string, arg_dw_size, "%02d/%02d/%d  %02d:%02d", st_Local.wMonth, st_Local.wDay, st_Local.wYear, st_Local.wHour, st_Local.wMinute);

    if (S_OK == dw_Return)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

bool AttributeLastAccessDirectory(const char* arg_path)
{
    HANDLE handleFile;
    char bufferLastAccessTime[MAX_PATH];
    char pathDirectory[MAX_PATH];

    strcpy(pathDirectory, arg_path);

    handleFile = CreateFileA(pathDirectory, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (handleFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (GetLastWriteTimeDirectory(handleFile, bufferLastAccessTime, MAX_PATH))
    {
        printf("\n\t\t");
        printf("%s", "Last Accessed: \t");
        printf("%s\n", bufferLastAccessTime);
        CloseHandle(handleFile);
        return true;
    }

    CloseHandle(handleFile);
    return false;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AttributeLastAccessDirectory("C:\\Users\\mkahs\\Desktop\\Sample\\");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a problem statement. We don't know, what you expect the code to do, nor do we know, what the observed behavior is. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea):

> To open a directory using **CreateFile**, specify the **FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS** flag as part of *dwFlagsAndAttributes*. Appropriate security checks still apply when this flag is used without **SE_BACKUP_NAME** and **SE_RESTORE_NAME** privileges.

Your `CreateFileA` function call currently sets the *dwFlagsAndAttributes* parameter (the sixth parameter) to 0. Setting it to `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` should fix the problem.

Also, there is no need for the `pathDirectory` array and the call to `strcpy` that sets it. The `arg_path` parameter can be passed to `CreateFileA` directly.